# Class convert error when I assign a list of class instances to a Firebase document

Tags: flutter, firebase

In firebase I have a collection of instances of a user-defined class, call it class A.
One of the fields of such a class is a List of another user-defined class, call it class B.
So I have something like:

```
class A {
  ...
  List<B> names;
  ...
}
```

At the run time, I manage to create a list of class B instances without errors. Call this list list_of_B_instances.

```
p['names'] = list_of_B_instances;
```

where p is a document, defined as class A instance. So far s good, However, when I try to upload this to Firebase, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid argument (dartObject): Could not convert: Instance of 'B'
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
p = A(
  names: list_of_B_instances,
  …
);
```

Comment: My apologies, I think I have not provided all the details of what I do: first I create a json with all the info that "p" should have, This is why I have the code p['names'] = list_of_B_instances; Then I call the constructor                                        _FromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return A(json['xx'] as String,
      ....
      'names': json['names'] as List<B>,
   ....);
}. Which ultimately does what you suggest, correct?